# Python - How do I go about deleting a custom maya UI window when the user clicks outside of it?

Tags: python, user-interface, window, maya

I have a custom window that basically acts as a popup whenever a user clicks on a shelf item.

```
def drawUI(): 
    mouse_pos = QtGui.QCursor().pos()
    print 'mouse x: %d y: %d' % (mouse_pos.x(), mouse_pos.y())
    if cmds.window("SET_SELECTION_UI", exists = True):
        cmds.deleteUI("SET_SELECTION_UI", window=True)

    cmds.window("SET_SELECTION_UI", title = "Example", wh = (102, 300), rtf=True, mnb = False, mxb = False, tb = False, sizeable = False, tlc=(mouse_pos.y(),mouse_pos.x()))
    cmds.columnLayout()
    cmds.button(label = "Set 00",   w = 100, command=button00)
    cmds.button(label = "Set 10",   w = 100, command=Button10)
    cmds.button(label = "Set 25",   w = 100, command=Button25)
    cmds.separator( height=10, style='double' )
    cmds.button(bgc=[1,1,1], label = "Cancel", w = 100, command=DeleteButton)
    cmds.showWindow() #shows window

    cmds.window("SET_SELECTION_UI", edit=True, tlc=(mouse_pos.y(),mouse_pos.x()))
```

The window appears properly, all the buttons do what they're supposed to do, and whenever a button is pressed, I delete the window. It's all fine and dandy.

What I'm trying to do, is to detect when the user clicks anywhere outside of the window so that I can delete the UI (much like a pop-up menu works).

Thanks!

**ANSWER**

I've integrated Cronicryo's script and suggestions into my own and it works perfectly now! Here it is:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import maya.OpenMayaUI as omui
import pymel.core as pm
from shiboken import wrapInstance

fltr    = None
qtObj   = None
_WINDOW_NAME_ = "SET_SELECTION_UI"

class FilterObj(QtCore.QObject):
    def eventFilter(self, obj , event):
        print event.type()
        if event.type() == event.WindowDeactivate:
            print "focused out"
            pm.window(_WINDOW_NAME_,edit=True,visible=False)
            return True #must return a bool set False to allow normal events to pass through or True to stop any further events
        else:
            return False

def run(): 
    global fltr
    global qtObj

    if qtObj:
        del qtObj

    mouse_pos = QtGui.QCursor().pos()
    print 'mouse x: %d y: %d' % (mouse_pos.x(), mouse_pos.y())
    if pm.window(_WINDOW_NAME_, exists = True):
        pm.deleteUI(_WINDOW_NAME_, window=True)

    win = pm.window(_WINDOW_NAME_, title = "Set Select", mnb = False, mxb = False, tb = False, sizeable = False)
    pm.columnLayout()
    pm.button(label = "Do nothing",   w = 100)
    pm.separator( h=15, w=100, style='doubleDash' )
    pm.button(bgc=[1,1,1], label = "Cancel", w = 100, command=DeleteButton)
    pm.showWindow(win) #shows window

    pm.window(_WINDOW_NAME_, edit=True, wh = (102, 245),tlc=(mouse_pos.y(),mouse_pos.x()))

    qtObj = wrapInstance(long(omui.MQtUtil.findControl(_WINDOW_NAME_)), QtGui.QWidget)
    fltr = FilterObj()
    qtObj.installEventFilter(fltr)

def DeleteButton(*args):
    pm.deleteUI(_WINDOW_NAME_)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**:

i took a look and it looks like there is no focus signal that gets emitted. seems like the only way to do it is to make a custom qt window and re-implement the focus functions or to install an event filter which is almost non evasive

```
import maya.OpenMayaUI as omui
import pymel.core as pm
pysideSupport = True
try:
    from PySide import QtGui
    from shiboken import wrapInstance
except:
    pysideSupport = False

win = pm.window("aaa")
win.show()

from PySide import QtCore

class FilterObj(QtCore.QObject):
    def eventFilter(self, obj , event):
        print event.type()
        if event.type() == event.WindowDeactivate:
            print "focused out"
            return False #must return a bool set False to allow normal events to pass through or True to stop any further events
        else:
            return False


qtObj = wrapInstance(long(omui.MQtUtil.findControl("aaa")), QtGui.QWidget)
fltr = FilterObj()
qtObj.installEventFilter(fltr)
```

**ORIG**:

this is a snippet of my own code that ive used to connect to the destroy signal of a window.
you can do the same of losing window focus

```
import maya.OpenMayaUI as omui
pysideSupport = True
try:
    from PySide import QtGui
    from shiboken import wrapInstance
except:
    pysideSupport = False


def onUIDelete(uiName, function):
    """
    extends mayas ui by being able to run a function when the ui gets deleted
    this requires maya to have PySide

    """
    if pysideSupport:
        if isinstance(uiName, pm.ui.PyUI):
            uiName = uiName.name()
        qtObj = wrapInstance(long(omui.MQtUtil.findControl(uiName)), QtGui.QWidget)
        qtObj.destroyed.connect(function)
    else:
        pm.error("Maya doesn't have PySide Support")
```

Comment: Thanks @cronicryo, but assume that I have little knowledge of widgets, pyside and Qt. What calls onUIDelete ? Is that a built-in event function that triggers automatically when a specific event happens or do you have to explicitely call it, in which case, how/where? Thanks,

Comment: @croncryo I've edited my question to reflect your answer...and came up with more questions! :)

Comment: @TheMsika print statements help a lot! if you noticed the theres a persistent print in the filter and its not printing. With qt its all object oriented because its based on C++ so why is it not running? simply because the fltr variable doesnt exist any more in run funciton and gets deleted you can simply add the line "global fltr" on the first line beneath def run.

your second problem is your gonna run into is  an object is trying to delete itself while its still running and will indefinitely crash maya. youll need some sort of time out and then delete it

Comment: without getting into specifics of threading you can look into QTimer